# Help with MySQL Regular Expression - Grabbing the Year

Tags: mysql, regex

I've never been very good with regular expression - and I'm looking for someone to help building a simple regex for MYSQL that queries DB for the following pattern:

```
Could be anything here (YYYY)
```

Basically - I want to be able to query the DB to return all rows that match that pattern.

Sample Query:

```
SELECT title from myTable where title REGEX '$(YYYY)$'
```

Any advice or help on this?

UPDATE: The YYYY entry is a Year, like 2011 or 2010. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT title from myTable where title REGEXP '[(][0-9]{4}[)]'
```

(By the way, it's `REGEXP` with a P)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for but try this one:

`SELECT title from myTable where title REGEXP '.*\([0-9]{4}\).*'`

EDIT: Too slow:) Use Vache answer.

Comment: +1 but you don't need the `.*` 's in there, they are implied when using regexp.

Comment: Yeah, true - thanks. I've sometimes forgot about this because in some implementations/languages they are not appended.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT title from myTable where title REGEXP '[(][0-9]{4}[)]'
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html
and: http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2337

For more info.

Answer (score -2):

How about the simple (but a little slow)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%yyyy%';
```

The % sign is the wildcard so this samplequery would return any rows where "field" contains 'yyyy'.

E.g:

```
yyyyfoobar or fooyyyybar or fooyyyy
```

would all be found by this query.

Disregard this answer, since it was posted before the clarification Edit.

Comment: -1, the OP is looking for a year, so he wants to match numbers, not the actual string 'yyyy'.

Comment: This was not in original question. Please reconsider.

Comment: The title does say `Grabbing the Year`, you could have guessed. ;)